# android logcat read unexpected eof in android 6.0 or android 7.0

Tags: android, android-logcat

I think it is that the log is too much lead to the problem， because I increase the ring buffer of the logd，just Logcat -G 5m ，it will make the problem happen slowly，but it still have。how can I solve this question
[image]

Comment: google logd ring buffer manager  maybe have bug